# SQL Statement with IN CASE

Tags: select, case, where-clause

```
SELECT user 
FROM userlist zH with(nolock) 
where zH.user in (case when zh.trait='1' then ('B', 'HO', 'KO', 'PL','APP','2A','2B') else ('O') end)
```

can this statement with the where-in-case work? i hope you get what i meant. thanks.

Comment: execute if it works then super..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  [user]
FROM    userlist zH WITH ( NOLOCK )
WHERE   ( zh.trait = '1'
          AND zH.[user] IN ( 'B', 'HO', 'KO', 'PL', 'APP', '2A', '2B' )
        )
        OR ( zh.trait <> '1'
             AND zH.[user] IN ( 'O' )
           )
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the contents. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested case statement, like

```
SELECT user 
FROM userlist zH with(nolock) 
where 'true' = 
   (case when zh.trait = '1' 
       then 
           case when zH.user in ('B', 'HO', 'KO', 'PL','APP','2A','2B') 
               then 'true'
               else 'false'
           end
       else 
           case when zH.user = 'O'
               then 'true'
               else 'false'
           end
   end)
```